# How do you prove the stable marriage lattice is distributive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that the stable matching Lattice is distributive, i.e., if M1,M2,M3 are stable matching
then:
M1 join (M2 meet M3) = (M1 join M2) meet (M1 join M3) and
M1 meet (M2 join M3) = (M1 meet M2) join (M1 meet M3)

Answer (score 1):

The join and meet operations of the stable matching lattice are just max and min, respectively, with respect to the preferences of each person.  Fix a man $m$. If $m$'s partners in $M_1$ and $M_2$ are, respectively, $w_1$ and $w_2$, then in the join of $M_1$ and $M_2$, the partner of $m$ is $\max(w_1,w_2)$, where the max is taken with respect to the (totally ordered) preference list of $m$.

Therefore, to prove that the lattice is distributive, it is enough to prove that the lattice of a totally ordered finite chain (with respect to operations min, max) is distributive, but this is easy to do.